# How to fetch last character and increment it in sql

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
  select case
            when Right('BPUREN_3',1) Like '[A-Z]' 
            then concat('BPUREN','_1')
            else 
              concat('BPUREN_3',right('BPUREN_3',1)+1)
              End
```

I want output as BPUREN_4 But I am getting the result as BPUREN_34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case
    when Right('BPUREN_3',1) Like '[A-Z]' then 'BPUREN_1'
    else concat(Left('BPUREN_3', 7),right('BPUREN_3',1)+1)
    End
```

No need to `concat('BPUREN','_1')` it will always be 'BPUREN_1'

You could change `Left('BPUREN_3', 7)` to `Left('BPUREN_3', LEN('BPUREN_3') - 1)` if 'BPUREN_3' could change in length (for example if its a parameter in your real code)

Answer (score 0):

`concat('BPUREN_3', right('BPUREN_3', 1)+1)` -- `concat` combines two strings together and returns a string.  So you are combining `BPUREN_3` with 4 (outputting the `BPUREN_34`).  Instead change `BUREN_3` to`BPUREN_`

Comment: No its a parameter and value being passed as input. so if its BUREN_3 it should become BUREN_4

Comment: @user3331421 In what context are you speaking of?  The concat? What is the parameter and value being passed as input?